# Is it mandatory to use GET, PUT, POST, DELETE verb in action controller methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a action controller method which does fetching the data from server, clearing the data in the server. This method works without specifying the action verbs like GET, PUT etc...

but few of the existing methods have GET, PUT etc.. verbs. But is it mandatory to put those verbs in the method? what is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0):

GET used default method, you don't have to specify it. It's a good practice to use GET to retrieve data. POST is to add data, update and delete.

PUT and DELETE comes from RESTFul services, where recommended to use:

GET - for retrieving
POST - for adding new data
PUT - for updating data
DELETE - for deleting

So, you have to specify PUT, POST and DELETE, if you want your controller to process these types of request

Comment: will it cause serious error, if i dont specify them in controller

Comment: @Naruto You just might get unexpected behavior of your application

Answer (score 0):

It is **not Mandatory** to specify those verbs **every time** to a controller action.

But, some times it becomes necessary to explicitly mention them. Other wise there would be an vulnerability.

If you want the controller action respond only to **POST** action , you need specify that controller actions as `[HttpPost]`

Other wise, it will **respond to GET action** and you will get error result